# update picture in listview onclick

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a listview with pictures and texts in each element. I have to be able to change one of the image if the user clicks on it and change it back to the original if the user clicks it again. I have a base adapter class that i use to add the data to the listview. in the getview method i set a onclick listener to the image to change it. The problem i'm having is it only changes if i scroll away from the element and come back to it. how can i change so that it will update the listview with out scrolling away from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after you change the image src in your listViewAdapter (who extends BaseAdapter)

eg.

```
public class ProductItemListView extends ListView {

    public ProductItemListView() {
        super(context);
        mProductAdapter = new ProductItemAdapter(context);
        this.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);
    }
}



public class ProductItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...

        myImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.other_image);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) on your `ListView`.

The rest is pretty straight-forward using `ImageView.setImageDrawable` or similar.